# How do I combine two lists of strings at every other element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How would I go from

```
lst1 = ['the', 'brown', 'jumps', 'the', 'dog']
lst2 = ['quick', 'fox', 'over', 'lazy']
```

to this output:

```
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

without defining a new function?

So far I've tried:

```
insertcounter = 1
for k in lst2:
    lst1.insert(insertcounter, k)
    insertcounter += 1
```

But it's just inserting the entire lst2 at the first index instead of looping through. I'm sure the answer is in plain sight but I'm a noob and it's not hitting me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [`more_itertools.roundrobin`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin) can do this.

Comment: @FCo added what I've tried so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `insertcounter += 1` to `insertcounter += 2`.

Comment: funny how nobody noticed this simple solution, lol, everyone else (myself included) tried doing basically something new

Comment: I knew it was hiding in plain sight rip. I feel less idiotic now LOL

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I will try this way:

It's similar with *roundrobin* but *maybe* faster:  it produces the same output as roundrobin(), but may perform better for some inputs (in particular when the number of iterables is large).  If the interables is small, it prob. will make a big difference though.

For the sake of completely honest with this lib, you have to install it first by doing *pip install more_itertools*.   Thanks @Matiiss reminder.

```
>>> from more_itertools import interleave_longest
>>> list(interleave_longest(lst1, lst2))
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
>>>
```

Comment: considering that the number of iterables is smaller, `roudrobin` should perform better here, also doesn't this require a `pip` install to begin with?

Comment: there is no `more_itertools` in pure Python...

Comment: uh what? you are using `more_itertools.interleave_longest` stating that it's faster than `more_itertools.roundrobin` while the documentation clearly states the opposite, `more_itertools` is not a built-in library hence requires to be installed, which should be mentioned

Comment: Please re-read the doc - it's quoted literally as it is;  This function produces the same output as roundrobin(), but may perform better for some inputs (in particular when the number of iterables is large).

Comment: yes, it's saying that `interleave_longest` performs better with a large number of iterables, while for `more_itertools.roundrobin` it performs better with a small number of iterables, which is the case here, there are two iterables, that's not a large number of them, that's a small number of iterables so `more_itertools.roundrobin` should be faster in this case

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `range` and `zip`:

```py
lst1 = ['the', 'brown', 'jumps', 'the', 'dog']
lst2 = ['quick', 'fox', 'over', 'lazy']

for i, word in zip(range(1, len(lst2)*2, 2), lst2):
    lst1.insert(i, word)

print(lst1)
# ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LU5BDsIwDLv3Fbm1RRXSxg2JlyAOg3VbYSQl6xjb50uDyMWOY1uJaxoIDzmPU6rgBGedBq8d6CvTgkLu8zNOQv6Hlnp9UcVe/@yvOdweonf0EaC3Z8Gx2dbiUx0xBAcLcQsBYQvRcIO9N5WD0aORIrurHdS2CLIcFZSRf/YBJ8/J/PNWqcgBk2Qqq3L@Ag)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the range of the longer list and trap IndexError exceptions as needed:

```
lst1 = ['the', 'brown', 'jumps', 'the', 'dog']
lst2 = ['quick', 'fox', 'over', 'lazy']
out = []
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    try:
        out.append(lst1[i])
        out.append(lst2[i])
    except IndexError:
        continue

print(out)
```

Result:

> ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

Comment: and append() and print() :)

Comment: well, it's included in the list of built-in functions, yet it's a `type` (as a bunch of other objects included there, smh /s)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! And sorry, by function I meant without defining* a new function. I'm new to Python so I may misspeak, but learning a lot from all of you - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to iterate over the lists together even if the lists have different length:

```
import itertools

output = []
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(lst1, lst2):
   output.append(i)
   if j:
       output.append(j)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = ['the', 'brown', 'jumps', 'the', 'dog',"murat"]
lst2 = ['quick', 'fox', 'over', 'lazy',"ali"]

newList=[]

if(len(lst1)>len(lst2)):
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
        newList.append(lst1[i])
        if(len(lst2)>i):
            newList.append(lst2[i])
else:
    for i in range(len(lst2)):
        newList.append(lst2[i])
        if(len(lst1)>i):
            newList.append(lst1[i])

print(newList)
```